# Using setValue instead of PostValue for LiveData

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-lifecycle

I have following Base class :

```
open class BaseViewModel<T>(
private val schedulerProvider: BaseSchedulerProvider,
private val requestObservable: Observable<T>
) : ViewModel() {

   private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

   private val _liveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<T>>()
   val liveData: LiveData<Resource<T>>
      get() = _liveData

   protected fun sendRequest() {
       _liveData.postValue(Resource.Loading)
       composeObservable { requestObservable }.subscribe({
           _liveData.postValue(Resource.Success(it))
       }) {
           _liveData.postValue(Resource.Failure(it.localizedMessage))
           Timber.e(it)
       }.also { compositeDisposable.add(it) }
   }
}
```

In one of my derived classes I have following logic :

```
class DetailViewModel(api: QapitalService, schedulerProvider: BaseSchedulerProvider,
        currencyFormatter: CurrencyFormatterDefault, goal: SavingsGoal
    ) : BaseViewModel<DetailWrapper>(schedulerProvider,
        Observable.zip(api.requestFeeds(goal.id).map { it.wrapper },
            api.requestSavingRules().map { it.wrapper },
            BiFunction<List<Feed>, List<SavingsRule>, DetailWrapper>
            { feeds, savingRules -> DetailWrapper(feeds,
                savingRules.joinToString { it.type },
                feeds.asWeekSumText(currencyFormatter)
            ) })) {

    init {
        sendRequest()
    }

    class DetailWrapper(
        val feeds: List<Feed>,
        val savingRules: String,
        val weekSumText: String)
}
```

As you see in the sendRequest() method, I have **postValue(Loading)**. I believe it is on the main thread and there is no need for **PostValue** rather I can **setValue**.

But by using **setValue** when I click on Home hardware button and resume the app again, ProgressBar appears again. Why that happens?

When I use **PostValue**, progressBar does not appear when I resume the app.

**I have made some other similar projects and I did not face which the issue that I explained above, but that projects were a single Activity and multiple fragments using Navigation component. In the above project I have multiple Activities with multiple fragments which are getting attached to the Activities layout.**

Full source code can be found : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/SavingGoals-Cache

Hore is my progressBar in my fragment_detail layout :

```
<ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:showLoading="@{vm.liveData}" />
```

And here is `showLoading` binding adapter :

```
@BindingAdapter("showLoading")
    fun showLoading(view: ProgressBar, resource: Resource<*>?) {
        view.visibility = if (resource is Resource.Loading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
```

Comment: Where else you are calling sendRequest? postValue is an asynchronous method and I think postValue is called very frequently in your sendRequest once the data is loaded for the first time. So the system will only keep the latest value, so you are not able to see the ProgressBar. But if you use setValue, the value is set first as it is an asynchronous call and then postValue will be handled. This might be the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: I only call sendRequest() in init method of this ViewModel. It called in other ViewModels but they have a different lifecycle with this one :)

Comment: okay. So you mean to say whenever you are resuming the app a new instance of ViewModel will be created? and have you considered my second point about setValue and postValue?

Comment: No there will be no new instance of ViewModel, just progressBar becomes visible. I have tried other project and I did not have this issue as I written bold in the question, that is why it is a bit strange for me.

Comment: yeah, Strange behaviour. I will clone and will to try to find out the issue in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me know if you found out the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded my project using a single Activity and multiple fragments using Navigation component, and the problem that I explained in the question resolved.

As I mentioned I was using multiple Activities with multiple fragments, as a result I reported that in [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180100694)